# How to access a html fields value inside razor function in MVC C#?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

How to access html control's value inside a function in razor syntax?
Suppose I have a hidden field :

```
@Html.Hidden("ActiveTab","Task")
```

I need to access this field's value from a function in razor view.
Would appreciate example using explanations.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to access this via your server-side code or client-side (like Javascript)?

Comment: Hi Rion,
I need it from Server side. I mean a function in razor code in .cshtml file.
like :
@functions {

    // Add code here.

}

Comment: I don't know if that is going to be possible. The `Html.Hidden()` helper is simply going to render an `<input />` tag which after it is rendered, you really will not be able to access it (outside of client-side code), until it's containing `<form>` is posted to the server.

Comment: Once you post the data, the hidden field is also posted, store this value in a ViewBag and retrieve it in the server side. Note - You cannot directly access the hidden field data coz the server code will first execute and then the client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would expect, this is going to render a hidden `<input />` tag within your View.

Once it's rendered, if you need to access it, you'll likely want to do so through Javascript using the `id` property that will match your first parameter (in this case "ActiveTab") :

```
<script>
    // Get the value of your hidden field using Javascript
    var active = document.getElementById('ActiveTab').value; // yields "Task"
</script>
```

Razor on it's own isn't really going to be able to access this in a server-side manner without actually posting your `<form>` that contains it. All the `Html.Hidden()` helper is going to do is render the appropriate client-side markup for it (and it's up to the server to handle it once it is posted).

Comment: Hi ,
Do I need to enclose the syntax inside <script> </script> tags.

Comment: Yes, I've updated and added that. You'll also want to ensure that the `<script>` tag is placed at the bottom of your View to ensure that there aren't any issues with accessing the element.

Comment: OK, 
Can I reuse that variable ( var active) in later part of razor code.
I mean like this 
@ if ( active == "Notification")

Comment: Declaring it with that approach will actually make a Javascript variable, which will only be accessible via your client-side code (Javascript and not C# / Razor code). If you wanted to handle this, you might consider populating a Model with an `ActiveTab` property and passing it into your View. Then you could check it via `Model.ActiveTab == "Notification"` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt support.
Can I write this way :

<script>
    // Get the value of your hidden field using Javascript
Model.ActiveTab  = document.getElementById('ActiveTab') 
</script>
And later use Model.ActiveTab for my other use.

Comment: Negative. The two are completely exclusive of one another. Your Model-based code will need to be set within your Model / Controller prior to coming into the View.